# Flask serving Angular app with client side routing

Tags: typescript, flask, angular8

I am setting up an app that will have a simple Flask server and am using Typescript/Angular8 for the frontend - I'm relatively new to web and very new to Angular. The general scheme is to compile the frontend, then have Flask serve files from the directory these get compiled to. When compiling the frontend, we have the following configuration in the angular.json:

```
"options" {
  "outputPath": "dist/static",
  "deployUrl": "/static/",
  "baseHref": "/static/",
  ...
```

So the compiled js/html/assets get pushed down to a static folder.

I'll paint a minimal example of the issue I'm dealing with:

Say the flask server has a root endpoint defined:

```py
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return send_from_directory(config.dist_dir, 'index.html')
```

to serve the home page (where `config.dist_dir` is that static directory).

Now say I add routing to the angular frontend so that my app.component.html just contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and that home view gets pushed to a separate component (I'm calling it "Blah" here).

With this setup, I have the basic template for app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'blah', component: BlahComponent }
  { path: '', component: BlahComponent }
];
```

The Flask correctly serves the index.html which displays `BlahComponent` correctly, **but the problem is that `/static` gets added to the URL.** Subsequent requests from the browser won't work until you delete static from the url.

My current workaround is just to include the following class and use it as the LocationStrategy:

```js
export class TempPathLocationStrategy extends PathLocationStrategy {
  prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
    return super.prepareExternalUrl(internal).substr('/static'.length);
  }
}
```

This works for the moment but I feel like I have to be missing something - some sort of configuration for the client-side routing or for the package information that I'm missing.

One issue with this workaround is that now you can only hack on the frontend if you have the server going too (`ng serve` wants to serve from the static folder but if you delete that from the url it cannot keep serving).

Comment: Why do you need `static` in `baseHref` in first place?

Comment: Just to push web pages down one level. It’s not particularly necessary, but I’d like to know how to do the routing if it is done this way.